# postfix to send and receive mail from gmail

Tags: postfix

Friends... I have Ubuntu server 12.04 on my computer and I have installed postfix to configure mail server.I want to send and receive mail from other domain like gmail and yahoo.I have already get a free domain.what should I do for this.should I have a public IP address for this.

Comment: Just note that even if you do all the setup correctly, your ISP may block ports 25, 143, 465, 587, 993 etc and you'll get those errors like "The recipient server did not accept our requests to connect".

Answer (score 0):

Yes! If I do understand you right, would you be best of with a public static IP address for your domain.
Add a [mx record](http://www.google.com/support/enterprise/static/postini/docs/admin/en/activate/mx_faq.html) and a [spf record](http://www.openspf.org/SPF_Record_Syntax) to the domain dns server. 
A typical `spf` record could be `v=spf1 mx -all`.

To set up the server i suggest you to follow the instructions in the [Ubuntu serverguide](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/).

A good mail server stack could be to install:
[Postfix](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/postfix.html), [Dovecot](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/dovecot-server.html) and [mail filtering](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/mail-filtering.html).